# How deploy Unity build in Windows azure?

Tags: azure, unity-game-engine, azure-storage, facebook-unity-sdk

I am making one Unity game for Facebook and since I am trying Windows Azure, I would like to deploy two files to this server services(an html and unity3d files), for it, Could anybody help me to do it?
Thanks in advance
Alejandro

Answer (score 1):

Use a free tool like AzCopy (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2012/12/03/azcopy-uploading-downloading-files-for-windows-azure-blobs.aspx) to publish the files as public blobs to a public Storage Container.

If that doesn't work because you need to set some mime type information you can use Azure Websites (http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/publishing-with-git/).  You would need to include a web.config to define the additional mime types for the web server to use.

Answer (score 0):

Most servers require no configuration at all. We have to just upload the .unity3d file, and the accompanying html file but it doesn’t work on Azure. On Azure we have to add a custom mime type.
To do this here I have written a complete blog http://poojabaraskar.com/deploy-unity3d-game-in-windows-azure/